# Can't install wine on Kali Linux 4.18.10

Tags: kali-linux

I can't install wine. I type

```
apt-get install wine32
```

And I have this error

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package wine32 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source

E: Package 'wine32' has no installation candidate
```

Linux User 4.18.0-kali2-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.18.10-2kali1 (2018-10-09) x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: You need to [add repository to sources list](https://wiki.winehq.org/Debian). But [Offensive Security warns you not to do that](https://docs.kali.org/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories). Please strongly consider using another distro.

Comment: Why on earth would you need wine on Kali? Is there a Windows forensics application that runs under wine but has no Kali equivalent?

Comment: I already added all the repository to the sources list obviously

Comment: @roalma Ollydbg

Comment: I solved using the git repository of wine:
https://github.com/wine-mirror/wine

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `dpkg --add-architecture i386 && apt-get update && apt-get install wine32`

Comment: Not working for me, I needed to install wine from the git repository to have it..